# Unspecified bindings for lifecycle phases in Maven?

Tags: maven

In the [lifecycle reference](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/lifecycles.html) page, the phases of the 3 lifecycles are given.

However, in the [built-in lifecycle bindings section](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html), there are phases with unspecified built in bindings. Some examples are:

- validate
- initialize
- generate-sources
- process-sources
- generate-test-sources
- process-test-sources
- generate-test-resources
- process-test-classes
- prepare-package
- pre-integration-test
- integration-test
- post-integration-test
- verify
- pre-clean
- post-clean
- pre-site
- post-site

What are the built in bindings for these phases? Why aren't them in the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

The `default` life cycle contains bindings for particular plugins. But there some phase which don't contain bindings.

If there is no binding for them as described in the [default bindings](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.9/maven-core/default-bindings.html) than there is simply no binding, cause there is no useful default.

Furthermore for the `pre-clean`, `post-clean` there are no bindings at the moment (based on the same reason), cause the default usage for the `clean` lifecycle is to use:

```
mvn clean
```

But there is no usefull plugin which could be bound to `pre-clean` so it's left open.

Comment: So no binding for a phase means that phase doesn't get executed. But then _why_ is that phase specified in the lifecycle at all? Why couldn't it just be left out?

Comment: The life cycle phases will be executed but if no plugin is bound to it you don't see any result of the execution...

Comment: But why don't these have any default bindings? Just in case somebody needs to do some tasks in these phases?